# prestashop 1.6 backoffice consuming to much bandwidth

Tags: prestashop, bandwidth, prestashop-1.6

my prestashop 1.6 website is consuming to much bandwidth of my server. I track down the problem and it looks like it is the back office that is causing it. how can i fix this? do i have to disable any module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on a whole lot of things. First off, how much bandwidth is it taking? Do you have a quota? With PrestaShop, combinations can sometimes take up a lot of resources. Do you have many combinations? Another option is that it is coming from third party modules.

On your server, open the /config/defines.inc.php file.
Find this line (around line 43): define('_PS_DEBUG_PROFILING_', false);
In this line, change "false" to "true".
Save your changes.

Now load any page of your store, either front-end or back-end, and it will display statistics at the bottom of the page. That should tell you where your server resources are allotted

Comment: Memory peak usage: 43.1 Mb in product page .. my monthly bandwidth for my server is 4gb and i consumed that all in less than a month.. so do you think that multiple user using the back office can caused this? There are four employee that is accessing my BO .. some of them upload a product everyday

Comment: this feature really help a lot